# how i can change this code from for loop to while loop in C program?

Tags: c

how i change it to while loop?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {

 int sum = 0; 

 int number; 

 for ( number = 2; number <= 100; number +=2 )


 {

 sum += number; 


 } 


 printf( "Sum is %d\n", sum ); 

 return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with that perfectly fine `for` loop?

Comment: Oh and yes, every `for` loop can be done as a `while` loop as well. Good books and tutorials would show the alternative `while` loop form, and it shouldn't be hard to find with a little searching.

Comment: nothing wrong with i just have homework want me to change it to while loop (:

Comment: @Venomous The label on the downvote button literally says "*This question does not show any research effort*". Well, this question doesn't. Have you made any attempt to do your homework yourself?

Comment: Don't be sorry; answer my question instead. Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? If not, that's what you should do next time. If you've tried, but you got stuck or it didn't work, ask about *that*.

Comment: @Venomous writing in all-caps is considered shouting on the internet, that's why Govind called it rude.

Comment: @Zoe oh i did not know that sorry

Comment: @melpomene im trying right now

Comment: @melpomene hi again, finally i solve the problem (: and i have another problem that im in struggle with ): this it:he want me to make the user insert the salary and the rate i dont know how to do it can you help me ): ? #include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
 double amount; 
 double salary=1000; 
 double rate = .05; 
 int year; 

 printf( "%4s%21s\n", "Year", "Amount on deposit" );
 
  year = 1;
 while( year <= 10){
 
 amount = salary * pow( 1.0 + rate, year );

 printf( "%4d%21.2f\n", year, amount );
 ++year;
 } 
return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop `for(init; cond; step) { loop-body; }` is equivalent to:

```
init;
while(cond)
{
     loop-body;
     step;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop can be made into a while loop like so:

```
int sum = 0;
int number = 2;
while(number <= 100){
    sum += number;
    number += 2;
}
```

A for loop is split into three parts. In the example `for(number = 2; number <= 100; number += 2)`, the first section `number = 2` means `number` starts as 2. The second section means the loop will continue as long as `number <= 100`. And the third sections means `number` will be increased by 2 after each cycle.